# updating mid-flight animations in core animation

Tags: ios, core-animation

Ive been using animation blocks making images fade in as I scroll down a large image gallery using a uiscrollview.

The images are uiviews backed with a subclassed calayer, the images are drawn on separate thread to minimise scrolling sticking. This is great but this means while you scroll down, loading so many images is now no problem, but the images just pop in when they are ready, with no finesse. So Just before the images come into view whilst scrolling I'm using an animation block to animate the images to 'spring' out. Obviously this causes sticking as I constantly keep committing animations on each image/view.

Ive been looking at using lower level ca-transactions or ca grouping, but does anyone know directly if there is an advanced way of whilst scrolling, adding/feeding these animation blocks(or a low level alternative to blocks) into the animation tree whilst the render is passing (in flight), without any blocking?

Each image has its own calayer, is grouping these layers causing the animations to delay?

Thanks apologies for my short understanding, in all the advanced explanations of core animations on apple and in forums no one has directly spoken about this problem or a way around this ( most discussion is on implicit changes to the presentation tree on existing animation objects, rather than a way a dynamically adding animation objects to the same rendering tree real time )

or could i be missing something simple on performance, has anyone had a similar problem of animating views whilst scrolling?

Comment: Have you checked on UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState?

Comment: yes I did thanks, no joy, I read that this doesn't help as this will only invalidate the current state set to that animation key.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?if no, could you explain it a bit more?